# How to apply overdraft charge to balance java

Tags: java

Hi guys I am trying to apply an overdraft charge of 50 on balance when user applies for an overdraft. My code is below:

```
public void Withdraw(double amount){

      int Charge = 50; //overdraft charge
     if (balance - amount < 0) { 

                if ((balance -Charge)- amount  <= -300) { //If withdraw + overdraft charge goes over -300 then overdraft limit has been exceeded
                    System.out.println("You have exceeded your Overdraft Limit, you will now be returned back to the menus");

                 } else { //if not exceeding bank balance
                    balance -= amount ;  //subtract amount from balance 

                    System.out.println("/");
                }
    }
}
```

What it currently does is just display the nagative number when applying for overdraft without subtracting the over draft charge how can I make it that when user applies for a overdraft they are charged an additional 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code to look like this

```
} else { //if not exceeding bank balance
                    balance -= (amount + Charge) ;  //subtract amount and charge from balance 
                    System.out.println("You have withdrawen £" + amount);
                    System.err.println("You now have a balance of £" + balance);
                    System.out.println("/");
                }
```